# XeTeX + Polyglossia: Incorrect presentation of Bengali glyph - how can I correct it?

Tags: xetex, polyglossia

I started using XeTeX with polyglossia for typesetting Bengali. I use the following command for turning on language-specific ligatures:

```
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{FONTNAME}
```

Everything seems to work fine, except that if a consonant is followed by U+09CD (Virama) followed by U+09AF (Bengali letter Ya), I do not get the expected glyph in the output. The ligature is not formed for some reason. All other combinations seem to work. I have tried with multiple fonts, so I do not think it is a font issue.

Here is a picture of the problem

[image]

Thanks a lot for your patience!

Setup: MikTeX 2.9.4476 on 32-bit Windows 7

Answer (score 3):

I have tried it out with the following code and as you can see, the ligature is only formed correctly in `Code2000`. Strangely enough, I get this error for all fonts except for `Code2000`:

```
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "script-not-exist"
* 
* Font 'ArialUnicodeMS' does not contain script 'Bengali'.
*************************************************
```

But when I look it up in `Font Book.app`, it tells me that at least `BanglaMN`and `BanglaSangamMN` *do* have the Bengali script (apart from `Code2000`).

In `TextEdit.app`, both `BanglaMN` and `BanglaSangamMN` have the correct ligated form for *kya,* which is even stranger. (`Arial Unicode MS` does not, though.)

From my point of view, this seems like a mixture of both a font and XeLaTeX (or fontspec) issue.

---

### Code:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}

\begin{document}

\newfontfamily\bengalifontA[Script=Bengali,Scale=10]{ArialUnicodeMS}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontB[Script=Bengali,Scale=10]{BanglaMN}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontC[Script=Bengali,Scale=10]{BanglaSangamMN}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontD[Script=Bengali,Scale=10]{Code2000}

\noindent {\bengalifontA ক্য }\vfill
{\bengalifontB ক্য }\vfill
{\bengalifontC ক্য }\vfill
{\bengalifontD ক্য }\vfill
\end{document}
```

---

### Output:

[image: Bengali Ligatures]